# action on two button for show fullcalendar and refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have this scenario

[image]

under a bootstrap menu
two button one for show a fullcalendar and one for add an event in calendar

```
<div class="card-body">
  <h5 class="card-title">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addEvent">Aggiungi Work</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showCalendar">Mostra Calendario</button>
  </h5>
</div>
```

now in JS or in other newbie method i want if is possible
when i click on the first button appear under the button in a div for example the insert event form like this

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalEvento" tableindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="box-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">nome:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="testoExtra">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Dettagli:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dettagli">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and when i click on the second button compare the fullcalendar (also the default)

is it possible ?
thanks a lot

i use codeigniter, bootstrap and js